# Multiple HSRP group on same VLAN interface

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, hsrp

I have Cisco Nexus 9k switch and following is my `HSRP` configured with `vPC`

```
interface Vlan100
  description *** Public_1 VLAN ***
  no shutdown
  mtu 9216
  no autostate
  no ip redirects
  ip address 71.201.101.2/23
  no ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
  hsrp 1
    preempt
    priority 110
    ip 71.201.101.1
```

Now i want to add new public subnet on same VLAN 100 so how do i add them on same HSRP

Does following will work?

```
  hsrp 2
    preempt
    priority 110
    ip 61.62.63.1
```

Anybody know full configuration how do that?

## EDIT

I have one LAB switch so i am trying to setup same scenario and getting this error when trying to add secondary IP, is this going to cause any issue?

```
N9k(config-if)# ip address 2.2.2.1/24 secondary
Disabling IP Redirects on Vlan111 :secondary address configured.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the VIP i in the same subnet as the secondary address(s), This should work.  You can verify it by typing

```
show hsrp
```

If the VIP is active, it should be working.

Comment: Its working!!!!!